# Is it possible to have a different 'edit' view for mosaic tiles in plone?

Tags: plone

Basically, how can you have a custom 'edit' view for a mosaic tile?

#### Long version

When using the [mosaic editor](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.mosaic) in plone 5 with a custom tile, you provide a view template to render the tile, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal" xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal">
    <body>
         Content here...
         <img src="${view/image}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This renders as a draggable tile when you edit the layout, like this:

[image: example]

However, when the content of this tile is complex, the performance of the editor becomes terrible and in some cases (eg. video and react components), completely breaks the editor.

How can you have a 'placeholder' view (eg. fixed image) that renders only when editing a page / dragging a tile?

(NB. I see inspecting the page element, that a 'WebDAV' lock is applied to the page while it is being edited, but this doesn't seem useful in any way, as it is not unique to the user's session, ie. logged out users will also seem the same page state.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way I can think of is doing it with css/js.

When you start dragging a tile around the `#content` div gets the class `.mosaic-panel-dragging` so you know there's currently a tile dragged around.

Additionally the tile which is dragged gets the class `.mosaic-original-tile` (only god knows why it is named like that)

With this information you could either set some components of your tile to `display: none;` or do some javascript action when the classes change and you detect your specific tile.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if you want to render the tile in the mosaic layout editor differently from when it is rendered in the view, you could take advantage of the extra query string parameter: ?_layouteditor=true. Also, only the request for the view should provide ISubRequest e.g. [p.a.standardtiles](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.standardtiles/blob/e51f620ef320603915af09fa4a8d6a51e1b4db13/plone/app/standardtiles/html.py#L32-L33).